# Retrieve Special fields from Active Directory using JMapMyLdap - Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: joomla, ldap

I'm stuck at this since last 4 hours. I am using Joomla 3.3.6 CMS and JMapMyLdap extension. I'm able to login with my active directory username and password. Extension is only mapping username, email, Full name.

I've few additional attributes like title, manager, department etc. I can see these values in "Debug" functionality of extension but I am not able to find way to retrieve it. Please see attachment for more information.

Did anyone know if JMapMyLdap provides special object that retrieves all these attributes. If yes, then please provide the way to get this object. Please note that, I'm using PHP Module to inject PHP code in article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with following code:

```
$user = & JFactory::getUser();
$ldap = SHLdap::getInstance();
$ldap->connect();
$dn = $ldap->getUserDn($user->username);
$read = $ldap->read($dn);
```